# Java version not pointing to right environment variable to increase PermGen size

Tags: java, version, permgen

I am not sure if a similar question is posted earlier, when I looked for help, it all sounded similar but I am still not clear. I have two questions,

1. I have 2 jres in my windows 7 machine jre 1.7 and jre 1.8. I have 1.7 alone in my environment variables but when I do a

   ```
   java -version
   ```

   in command prompt and it shows

   ```
   java version "1.8.0_121"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
   ```
2. The purpose I want to fulfill is, I want to increase my Permgen size for java application in order to do a memory profile using jre 1.7. Right now my memory profile crashes because of the default size

Comment: “I have 1.7 alone in my environment variables”—what environment variables are you talking about? Java doesn’t care about any environment variables when choosing the JRE version.

Answer (score 0):

> I have 1.7 alone in my environment variables but when I do a

Based on the version command, there is another one in your path. Execute the following in your cmd:

```
for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
```

I suspect it will be C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath in your path, which points to your 1.8 JRE. So you can remove that one or update it accordingly.

Comment: I just see an exe file, it does not say whether it is 1.8 or 1.7 _C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe_

Comment: @yellow Right click, properties and details should reveal it. If your path already points to the directory with the 1.7 directly, I would suggest removing the C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath from your path.